# Query Geoserver using lat/long with UTM store

Tags: geoserver, utm, srid

I have been using a Geoserver for years with my developers querying it using lat/long to get US parcel boundaries from a SQL Server store. I got a dataset with UK parcel boundaries but it's in EPSG:27700 (UTM). I can query it fine using UTM values but I need to use lat/long and I'm not sure what the trick is. The Geoserver lists the native SRS as EPSG:4326 for some odd reason. I think it should say EPSG:27700 for native and I want EPSG:4326 for declared, with either "reproject native to declared" or "force declared." Any guesses as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: 27700 is OSGB not UTM - are your coordinates large numbers or small numbers, large is 27700 and small will be 4326

Comment: The coordinates in the data I was given look like UTM (my mistake, newbie here). Here's an example in text form:
POLYGON ((360230.846 176528.235, 360233.993 176532.379, 360232.85000000003 176533.45, 360215.10000000003 176548.2, 360206.8 176555.1, 360202.15 176558.9, 360198.8 176554.80000000002, 360203.4 176550.95, 360209.45 176545.9, 360229.60000000003 176529.2, 360230.5 176528.55000000002, 360230.846 176528.235))

Comment: This link makes it sound like I should use the "Petroleum conversion" to change the values to WGS-84:
http://communityhub.esriuk.com/geoxchange/2012/3/26/coordinate-systems-and-projections-for-beginners.html

Comment: Just set epsg 27700 as declared and geoserver will take care of the rest

Comment: But I need to pass in lat/long. I've tried that and it doesn't render the polygons, unless I use the big decimal values instead (what I thought was UTM).

Comment: I solved the problem by reprojecting the shapefile that was the source of the SQL data as 4326, then reimporting into SQL Server. I can't post that as an answer because @iant put this question on hold.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a case of geoserver can't find implicitly what's an EPSG so it's setting 4326 - try to define it explicitly. If you're using shapefiles create .prj file, if PostGIS convert datatype for column into geometry(Geometry,27700)...

It's just a guess... not enough details in question :)

Comment: I'm using a SQL Server database. When I use Stsrid it says it's 27700.

Comment: OK, but sometimes that's not enough for geoserver... what is a ddl for this table? Maybe try "alter table table_name alter geom_column column type geometry(Geometry,27700);"